# How to convert entry from Tkinter into a list so that I can analyze it for my program

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, math, statistics

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
root.title("Random")
root.geometry("600x400")
root.resizable(False, False)


def open_saw():
    saw_wn = Tk()
    saw_wn.title("Random App - Spin a Wheel")
    saw_wn.geometry("600x400")
    saw_wn.resizable(False, False)

    saw_wn.mainloop()


def open_coin():
    c_wn = Tk()
    c_wn.title("Random App - Flip a Coin")
    c_wn.geometry("600x400")
    c_wn.resizable(False, False)

    Label(c_wn, text="                            ").grid(row=0, column=0)
    Label(c_wn, text="Flip the coin below!").grid(row=0, column=1)

    c_wn.mainloop()


def open_average():
    avg_wn = Tk()
    avg_wn.title("Random App - Flip a Coin")
    avg_wn.geometry("600x400")
    avg_wn.resizable(False, False)

    Label(avg_wn, text="                            ").grid(row=0, column=0)
    Label(avg_wn, text="Enter your values below to get the averages in mean, median, mode, and range").grid(row=0,
                                                                                                            column=1)
    entry_avg = Entry(avg_wn).grid(row=1, column=1)

    def calculate_mean():
        print(entry_avg.get().split(','))

    Button(avg_wn, text='test', command=calculate_mean).grid(row=2, column=1)


Label(root, text="                                                          ").grid(row=0, column=0)

title = Label(root, text="Welcome to Random")
title.config(font=("Yu Gothic UI", 24))
title.grid(row=0, column=1)

button1 = Button(root, text="             Spin a wheel             ", padx=80, pady=25, command=open_saw)
button1.place(x=2.25, y=100)

button2 = Button(root, text="Calculate mean, mode, median, and range", padx=20, pady=25, command=open_average)
button2.place(x=325, y=100)

button3 = Button(root, text="Flip a Coin", padx=125, pady=25, command=open_coin)
button3.place(x=2.25, y=200)

button4 = Button(root, text="Roll a die", padx=107.5, pady=25)
button4.place(x=325, y=200)

root.mainloop()
```

What I want is to get a list from the entry so that I can calculate mean, mode, median, etc but when I do, I receive an error. The error is below:

```
line 44, in calculate_mean
    print(entry_avg.get().split(','))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Please help as I am a beginner at programming and I am stuck on this. If you need additional info please tell me and I will give you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `Entry.grid` doesn't return anything (i.e. `None`). Try putting the `grid` call and the **`Entry`** instantiation on different lines in your `open_average` function:

```py
entry_avg = Entry(avg_wn)
entry_avg.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

instead of

```py
entry_avg = Entry(avg_wn).grid(row=1, column=1)
```